# Drive unreadable

Tags: hard-drive, bsod

So I've got this hard drive: I removed it from a computer because it was getting bsod when I tried to boot it. I bought a external case for the drive, and hooked it up via USB to my computer. It seems to recognize the drive, but it cannot read the drive. Do you all have any idea how I can get the data off the drive?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different tools out there on the Windows side of things

I've had good success with File Scavenger from [Quetek](http://www.quetek.com) and used their Disk Recoup tool to image disks before recovery. Their trialware version at least will give you an idea of whether it wil be able to recover anything.

I've heard good things about R-Studio from [r-Tools Technology](http://www.data-recovery-software.net/)

There are a few different tools out there but first things first I'd recommend imaging the disk with an imaging tool before you try any recovery activity.

I'd recommend searching google for data recovery software and see which one(s) would best suit your needs from a recovery, price and usability perspective.